# Django CMS - Aldryn Bootstrap broken grid system

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-cms, grid-system, bootstrap-grid

I have recently started to develop a website using Django CMS. Everything is going perfectly fine apart from the broken grid system whilst using Alrdyn Bootstrap.

All other components seem to be working fine, but the grid system will not comply with the settings I am inputting within the CMS, for example.

If I state `col-lg-4 col-xs-6` within a class, the component will comply with the first class only, and will not shrink when in mobile.

If anyone has any insight I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your feedback. It was actually an error on my part. I was not up to date with the new Bootstrap 4 CSS. col-xs-x is now not part of their styling, it is now just col-x

Answer (score 0):

We have never experienced issues with the class output. It might be a misconfiguration on the frontend setup eventually.

Is it working when you try to mock the markup in your project rather than using the addon?

Comment: Please, don't ask questions in the answers. Use comment under the question for such cases.